# How to read / write XMP sidecar file with Adobe XMP Toolkit?

Tags: objective-c, adobe, toolkit, xmp

I can't find any example code on using the Adobe XMP Toolkit for reading and writing XMP sidecar files.

I can read and write XMP tags into a JPEG file fine.  So how do you do it with a sidecar file?

Anyone got some sample code to help?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out.

Just read the XMP sidecar file into a buffer, and then use ParseFromBuffer() to parse the XML data, then use GetProperty() to get the tag I want.